# Book series with humans vs. Demons and dragon bone ships

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, demons

I'm looking for a series of books about a war between humans and demons who traveled to floating chunks of shattered worlds via boats made of dragon skin and bones?

I remember a couple of wizards, a guy that uses a cloak as a weapon, and a scorpion demonlord fighting other demonlords for dominance.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13563088-tiger-born

Comment: I don't understand why this would be marked as a duplicate. Even though the book that my post and the other post were looking for are the same, the contents of the other query doesn't sound anything like mine. Reading the other post, I would never have guessed it was the book I was looking for.

Comment: Have a read of [this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3431/why-would-vtc-as-duplicate-be-appropriate-for-a-story-identification-question). ***VTC as duplicate*** signposts people to an existing answer even where the question is superficially different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is [The Shattered World](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Shattered-World-Michael-Reaves/dp/0671559516) by Michael Reaves. The story takes place 1,000 years after a spell fragmented the world and survivors rely on ships of dragon skin to travel between the remains. A demon is the chief enemy as well.

> Centuries after the Necromancer had shattered the world and a group of wizards had bound the fragments together, there arises a new cult of magicians who want to resurrect the Necromancer to restore the slowly crumbling world

[image]

Comment: There is a sequel called *The Burning Realm*, which I remember as not being quite as good,

Comment: Yup, this seems to be the right book. Thanks for finding it for me and sorry for the delay at responding, I'm new and mistook the emails as spam.